# Spring REST - Construct link from Entity

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jpa

I'm using Spring + JPA and i have mapped an entity as an Database View, where i got all fields.

Now i want add one field to this entity and return a link image based to another field (all image are stored in resource/images)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Release")
public class Release implements Serializable
{
  private String user;
  private String userImageLink; // This is what i need to implement

  @XmlElement
  @JsonProperty
  public String getUser(){
    return user;
  }
  public void setUser(String user) {
    this.user = user;
  }

  public String getUserImageLink(){
    String imageUrl = /*i need to access to resource/images and create the link
                       If i run on localhost should return: http://127.0.0.1:8080/resources/images..
                       In production coudl return: http://myServer.com/resources/images..     
                      */;
    return imageUrl;
  }
}
}
```

The question is: how i can create and return this url ?

**MORE INFO**

If the table have 3 entry: User1, User2, User3

In the userImageLink i should return:

http://myserver.com/resources/images/User1.jpg
http://myserver.com/resources/images/User2.jpg

**Isn't important if the image exists or not in resources/image, i just need to compose the url as additional parameter when i access to the Service that take the data from my "Release" @Entity**

Comment: And what the URL would point to? You would better serve the resource from you DB since you cannot create a link to a DB record.

Comment: @Mistre83: If i rightly understood your question you want to construct link for each user profile image

Comment: @VipulParalikar: yes you have understand right. I've updated my answer with a little more detail, but yes... i want to create those urls (because i need to use that url in iPhone application that use WebService).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use your application `ServletContext` to generate the URL to your images.
This `ServletContext` cannot be accessed as a POJO into your JPA Entities but should be injected as a bean with the Spring container or you will end up with a `null` reference:

- Autowire a static instance variable as a `ServletContext` in your entity:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "Release")
public class Release implements Serializable
{
  @Transient
  private static ServletContext servletContext;

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
    log.info("Initializing ServletContext as [" +
                Release.servletContext + "]"); //Forces injection after bean construction.
  }

  @Autowired
  public void setServletContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
    Release.servletContext = servletContext; //Note the use of class name because that fiels hould be static thus shared by all instances.
  }
  //...
}
```

- Use the injected `ServletContext` to retrieve your webapp context path and build your image URL accordingly:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "Release")
public class Release implements Serializable
{
  //...
  public String getUserImageLink(){
    StringBuilder imageUrlBuilder = new StringBuilder(Release.servletContext.getContextPath())
        .append("/resources/images")
        .append(this.user);
    return imageUrlBuilder.toString();
  }
}
```

Remember to add annoation based bean scannig to recognize your servlet context bean and mark your `Release` class with `@Component` so it is scanned:

```java
<beans>
  <!-- ... -->
  <context:component-scan base-package="package.of.Release" />
<beans>
```

Thanks to @Ravi Thapliyal for [sharing the tip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16489076/2106516).

Answer (score 1):

1) Mark *userImageLink* as @Transient because JPA will use all properties of the class, unless you specifically mark them with @Transient as shown below:

```
@Transient
private String userImageLink;
```

2) Once ***Release*** entity class is populated with DB values then assuming that httpservletrequest object is available:

```
StringBuilder baseURL = new StringBuilder();
baseURL.append(request.getRequestURL().toString().replace(request.getRequestURI(), ""));

baseURL.append("/resources/images/").append(release.getUser());

release.setUserImageLink(baseURL);
```

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24122238/934719 provides a very simple solution to this problem which works without Autowiring etc:

```java
public static String getContextParameter(String param){
    try {
        InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext();
        Context environmentContext = (Context) initialContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
        return (String) environmentContext.lookup(param);
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```